# MongoDB - Query evenly distributed number of results based on field values and query limit

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

Let's say i have a collection with documents like this, with field "family" and 3 different values (fruit, vegetable, nut).

**Collection:**

```
{
  'name': banana,
  'family': fruit 
},
{
  'name': apple,
  'family': fruit 
},
{
  'name': orange,
  'family': fruit 
},
{
  'name': cucumber,
  'family': vegetable 
},
{
  'name': aubergine,
  'family': vegetable
},
{
  'name': walnut,
  'family': nut
}

# count family == 'fruit': 3
# count family == 'vegetable': 2
# count family == 'nut': 1
```

**Task:**

I would like to query this collection by passing a query limit and return documents evenly distributed depending on the values of the field "family".

**Example:**

A query with limit = 3 would return 3 documents with one document from every family, e.g.

```
{
  'name': orange,
  'family': fruit 
},
{
  'name': cucumber,
  'family': vegetable 
},
{
  'name': walnut,
  'family': nut
}
```

A query with limit = 5 would return 1 item of family 'nut', 2 items of family 'vegetable' and 2 items of family 'fruit'.

**Question:**

Is this possible with pymongo/ mongo and if so, how?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: you should try aggregation stage `$facet`